# Redirect structure in Nginx for expired domain names

Tags: nginx, vbulletin

I'm having a little trouble! Want to get help. Recently, I bought an expired domain name https://www.ar-hp.com after I installed the website on this domain. I realized that there are many 404 errors in webmastertool. Now I want to redirect the old links with the structure https: //www.ar-hp.com/vb / ...... to the homepage is https://www.ar-hp.com I'm using Use vps Centos and Nginx. Now I have to use any code to do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any URI beginning with `/vb`? Try: `location ^~ /vb { return 301 /; }`

Comment: I tried adding that line of code but it failed. But after I modified it location ^~/vb {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.ar-hp.com/ redirect;
  } it worked. Thank you very much